# AccessDenied (System.UnauthorizedAccessException) opening a XAML page in designer using VS2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, uwp-xaml, winui

I have created a brand new test WinUI 2 project in Visual Studio 2022 Pro. The project has only the standard boilerplate classes, nothing has been added/deleted/changed. When I try to open MainPage.xaml in VS designer I get the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Access is denied.

Access is denied.

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesignerHost.UwpHostPlatform.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<EnsurePackageRegisteredAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.HostServices.HostPlatformBase.<CreateSurfaceProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.SurfaceDesigner.Documents.SurfaceIsolation.SurfaceProcessContext.<EnsureSurfaceProcessAsyncCore>d__108.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.SurfaceDesigner.Documents.SurfaceIsolation.SurfaceProcessContext.<EnsureSurfaceProcessAsyncInternal>d__106.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlSurfaceDesigner.Views.IsolatedSurfaceImageHost.<CreateSurfaceAsync>d__67.MoveNext()

System.AggregateException
```

Environment: Windows 11 Enterprise v10.0.22621

My user is not a local administrator, but the error happens even when I run VS as Admin.

Any idea how I should go about troubleshooting the root cause?

Comment: Can you build and run the app successfully?

Comment: Yes, the project builds without errors. Only viewing the page in design mode is broken.

Comment: This might be VS designer issue and you could report it via VS: **Help->Send Feedback -> Report a problem**